# setuptools not getting dynamic version when using pyproject.toml

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml, version-numbering

I am using `setuptools` with a `pyproject.toml` file, and want `setuptools` to get the package version dynamically from the package contents. Instead, it is always setting the package version in the name of the generated file to `0.0.0`, even though the package version *inside* the package seems correct. What am I doing wrong?

- Python 3.11.6 on MacOS 14.1.2 (Sonoma)
- `setuptools` version 68.2.2
- `pip` version 23.3.1

Package structure:

```
.
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── invperc
│   └── __init__.py
└── pyproject.toml
```

- `invperc/__init__.py` contains only this:

```
__version__ = "0.2.0"
```

- `pyproject.toml` contains only this:

```
[project]
name = "invperc"
description = "Invasion Percolation"
readme = "README.md"
authors = [
    { name = "Greg Wilson", email = "gvwilson@third-bit.com" }
]
license = { text = "MIT License" }
dependencies = ["pandas", "numpy"]
dynamic = ["version"]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tools.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {attr = "invperc.__version__"}
```

- Command:

```
python -m build
```

- Screen output:

```
...many lines...
Successfully built invperc-0.0.0.tar.gz and invperc-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

- `dist/invperc-0.0.0.tar.gz` and `dist/invperc-0.0.0-py3-none-any-whl` now exist with `0.0.0` as version numbers (which is incorrect).
- But if I import and check:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ pip install $HOME/invperc/dist/invperc-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
$ python
>>> import invperc
>>> invperc.__version__
'0.2.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @SnoopJ@hachyderm.io for the answer: `[tools.setuptools.dynamic]` should be `[tool.setuptools.dynamic]` with a singular "tool" instead of a plural "tools". Now excuse me while I go scream into a pillow about the lack of any kind of warning message...

Comment: Maybe there is a linter out there that could have helped. Maybe this one (untested): https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/rules/invalid-pyproject-toml/

Comment: You are not the first  :)   https://pypi.org/project/UNKNOWN/#history

As usual, [distutils is to blame](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v68.2.2/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py#L1185-L1189).

Comment: If you would like to prepare a PR after screaming into the pillow, it would be pretty easy to add a warning into [setuptools' wrapper class](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blame/v68.2.2/setuptools/dist.py#L208) to detect "UNKNOWN" package name and "0.0.0" package version, which although valid are almost surely mistakes.